# Creating docker machine with hyperv driver on windows 10

Tags: docker-machine, boot2docker

I am trying to create docker machine with hyperv on windows 10 with following command

> docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "docker
>   Virtual Switch" machine4

But process end with error:

> Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting
>   for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60)
>   exceeded

Complete console is as follows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "docker Virtual Switch" machine4
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(machine4) Copying C:\Users\Manish Kumar\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\Manish Kumar\.docker\machine\
machines\machine4\boot2docker.iso...
(machine4) Creating SSH key...
(machine4) Creating VM...
(machine4) Using switch "docker Virtual Switch"
(machine4) Creating VHD
(machine4) Starting VM...
(machine4) Waiting for host to start...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

Debug info is as follows:

```
Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(machine4) Calling .GetSSHHostname
(machine4) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive ( Get-VM machine4 ).state
(machine4) DBG | [stdout =====>] : Running
(machine4) DBG |
(machine4) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(machine4) DBG | [executing ==>] : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive (( Get-VM machine4 ).networkadapters[0]).ipaddresses[0]
(machine4) DBG | [stdout =====>] : 192.160.1.100
(machine4) DBG |
(machine4) DBG | [stderr =====>] :
(machine4) Calling .GetSSHPort
(machine4) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(machine4) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(machine4) Calling .GetSSHUsername
Using SSH client type: external
&{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@192.160.1.100 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i C:\Users\Manish Kumar\.docker\machine\machines\machine4\id_rsa -p 22] C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe <nil>}
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255:
Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

In Hyper-V manager Host machine4 shows running and I am able to access the shell with root access.

Comment: Did u run that command in Admin mode\Powershell?

Comment: yes, I have tried with power shell and cmd  both as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
--generic-ssh-user
```

Let me know if it helps...